# Algorithm Suggestion for Diverging Data (Severity/Intensity Analysis)

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, evolutionary-algorithms, fuzzy-logic

I have four datasets for four different accidents; each dataset has the same parameters.  Some of the key parameters are changing their values from a "standard value". The more they change these key parameter values, the more the intensity increases. I want to compare the intensity of four accidents. I don't understand what algorithm to use. **Please suggest any ML, DL, soft computing, or evolutionary algorithm.**

I am already working on ANFIS (Adaptive Neuro Fuzzy Inference System), Please suggest more.